# How do I configure a reverse proxy to only proxy by file extension?

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-proxy

Let's say I have a vhost with a DocumentRoot and ProxyPass to an application server. I want the proxy to only forward requests with an extension of .xyz and .abc, but everything else should default to the doc root. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

Use LocationMatch:

```
<LocationMatch \.xyz$>
  ProxyPass http://some.where/else
</Locationmatch>
```

NOTE that since you are already providing an exact location, ProxyPass no longer requires one.